# how to represent a constantly moving signal on a MapView?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

Im just getting into MapViews on iOS, and want to show a car continuously moving as a blue dot. Would this be considered a map annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As an example check out the in Simulator Debug > Location > City Bike Ride . It does a slow loop round San Francisco(?)

To listen to updates implement in your Mapview delegate

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)amapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"im here! - %f,%f",userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude,userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude); 


}
```

and to adjust the annotation implement

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)amapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{

    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSLog(@"annotation = %@",((NSObject *)annotation));
    MKAnnotationView *annView;

    annView = [amapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"currentloc"];

    if(!annView)
    {
        annView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"] autorelease];
        ((MKPinAnnotationView *)annView).pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        ((MKPinAnnotationView *)annView).animatesDrop=TRUE;
        annView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
        annView.draggable = YES;
    }
    return annView;
}
```

The snip I have put in just goes with the default blue dot with accuracy circle  by returning nil for `MKUserLocation` but your implementation may be different.